# Getting error on input ['trades.csv']: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, csv, date

Write a function named "portfolio_value" that takes one parameter that is a string representing a filename that contains all the trades made by your company throughout the year and returns the total value of the portfolio on the date "2015-12-31". The total value is the sum of all the quantities of stock owned times the price for that stock at the end of the year.

```
def portfolio_value(filename):
        sum = 0
        seek_date = date(2015, 12, 31)
        with open(filename) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                y, m, d = row[3].split('-')
                current_date = date(y, m, d)
                if current_date == seek_date:
                    sum += float(row[1]) * float(row[2])
        return sum
```

I am getting error on input ['trades.csv']: an integer is required (got type str) for my code. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How does the file look like? and paste the full traceback as well

Comment: What's "part 3 of my code"? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52820862/edit) to include **full traceback** for your error. See also **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 0):

The date construct expects integers for year, month and day. But you are passing strings. You need to convert them to integers before passing it to constructors. Something like this:

```
current_date = date(int(y), int(m), int(d))
```